# Brownian Bridge as a Gaussian Process

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, brownian-motion

Let $B=\{B_t:t\geq 0\}$ be a standard Brownian motion. Define the Brownian brige $X=\{X_t:t\geq0\}$ as
$$
X_t=B_t-tB_1\quad t\in[0,1]
$$
Show that $X$ is (i) Gaussian and find its (ii) mean and (iii) covariance.

TWO questions:

1. Due to my lack of basics on the subsject, can I see a full proof of (ii) and (iii) ?
2. Can anybody check my attempt on (i)?

Attempt on (i).
Given that $X$ is a stochastic process by definition only need to show that $\sum_i^n \lambda_i X_{t_i}$ is Gaussian for some real $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,...,\lambda_n$.
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\sum_i^n \lambda_i( B_{t_i}-t_iB_1) & = \sum_i^n \lambda_i B_{t_i}-\gamma_iB_1 \ \ \text{ where }\gamma_i=\lambda_it_i \\
& = \sum_i^n \phi_iB_{t_i} +\gamma_i(B_{t_i}-B_1)\text{ where }\phi_i=\lambda_i-\gamma_i\\
& = \sum_i^n \phi_iB_{t_i} +\sum_i^n \gamma_i(B_{t_i}-B_1)\\
& = \sum_i^{n }\theta_i(B_{t_i}-B_{t_{i-s}} )+\sum_i^n \gamma_i(B_{t_i}-B_1),
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
scalar multiplication for normal distribution was used in every step. Then using the independence property of BM and the sum of independent normal variable property we satisfy the definition of a Gaussian process (doubts on the last equality/rearranging, namely on $\theta$ and $n$ in the first sum). $\blacksquare$

Comment: Wait... are you unable to compute E[X_t]? I am asking because if you are this puts some rather severe constraints on what a useful answer is.

Comment: I think I don't, I definitely did it somehow roughly in my economics studies but I am _definitionless_ in this respect.

Comment: Hmmm... And, what would be E[B_t] to you?

Comment: being a martingale $B_{t-1}$?

Comment: Sorry what do you mean for "WP". However is it something like: $E[B_t]=\sum_{i=1}^N B_t(\omega_i)P(\omega_i)$   or $\int_\Omega B_t(\omega)dP$

Comment: Really there is too much to explain to go from the questions you ask in the comments to the one in your post. Maybe somebody will post an answer (I have seen worse happening on the site), not me. (WP=Wikipedia.)

Comment: And now the ${\$}100$ question: what did you get from the accepted answer?

Comment: $E[B_t]=E[B_t-0]=E[B_t-B_0]=E[N(0,t-0)]=0$. Wheter it is true or not it is hard, conceptually, to understand it. I would comment the above as: "the BM at any point $t$ is a measurable function whose resulting position will be somewhere within the bell curve  generated from the starting point (which is $0$ for a standard BM) so the starting point is going to be the expected value. Makes sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Sorry that it is a bit messy. Hope it helps. You really need to look at some basic definitions.

You may also find this useful. Notice the tricks for these questions are identical.

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78087/i-want-to-show-e-alpha-tbe2-alpha-t-is-a-gaussian-process-and-i-find/81010#81010

EDIT there should be a minus sign in front of $\lambda_{n+1}$

Comment: After spending much time staring at your proof, I still don't understand how you grouped the terms together. Can you make it clear which terms you needed to add-subtract and how you grouped them?

Comment: you write $a_1X_1 + a_2X_2$ as $a_2(X_2-X_1) + (a_1+a_2)X_1$. and use this trick n times. This is a standard telescoping trick not unique to probability theory.

Comment: Got a reply on a 4 year old post, thanks so much!