# Prove the scaling property of a Brownian motion.

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

I have to prove that $X_t:=c^{-1/2}W_{ct}$, $t\ge0$, where $c>0$ is a constant is a Wiener process.

My attempt:

1) $X_0=c^{-1/2}W_0=0$

2) We know that $(W_t)$ has continuous trajectories. It implies that $(X_t)$ has also continuous trajectories since continuous function multiplied by a constant and with scaled argument is still continuous. Right?

3) Independence of increments. We know that $W_i-W_j$ and $W_k-W_l$ are independent for all $i, j, k, l\in\mathbb{R}^+$. Now, $X_i-X_j=c^{-1/2}(W_{ci}-W_{cj})$ nad $X_k-X_l=c^{-1/2}(W_{ck}-W_{cl})$ so $(X_t)$ has independent increments.

4) $X_{s+\epsilon}-X_s=c^{-1/2}(W_{c(s+\epsilon)}-W_{cs})$ ~ $N(0,\epsilon)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes, an alternative solution is observing/proving $X_t$ is a Gaussian process and its mean and covariance agrees with the mean and covariance of a Brownian motion, so they must have the same distribution.

here are two proofs I did for other things to show they are Gaussian.

[Brownian Bridge as a Gaussian Process](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/635707/brownian-bridge-as-a-gaussian-process/635936#635936)

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78087/i-want-to-show-e-alpha-tbe2-alpha-t-is-a-gaussian-process-and-i-find/81010#81010

$X_t$ is Guassian if $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \lambda_i X_{t_i}$ is a normally distributed with all value of $\lambda_i\in\mathbb{R}$ and $t_i\geq 0$.

Comment: How to observe that $X_t$ is Gaussian?

Comment: @luka5z what does it mean by a stochastic process is gaussian?

Comment: Gaussian process is a stochastic process whose realizations consist of random values associated with every point in a range of times (or of space) such that each such random variable has a normal distribution. Moreover, every finite collection of those random variables has a multivariate normal distribution.

Comment: @luka5z the multivariate normal condition is what i wrote. see the 2 links in  my edit to show similar processes to be gaussian - basically it uses independent increments of $W$.